# Print datetime each time I hit the return key

Tags: zsh, date

I am searching for a way of prefixing the `date` command every time I run a command on the terminal (I am currently using `zsh`).

The reason for this is that I usually run scripts that take a long time to complete, so I would like to have an idea on how much time the process has been running.

I know that this information is available on `[h]top`, and I also have on my `.zshrc` file a command that outputs how much did the process took to run, but this information of course is available once the command has finished, I would like to know **when** it started.

As an example, basically what I would like is that for each command `cmd`, what would run would be `date; cmd`.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I am looking something like this:

[image]

The counter on the bottom right is what I already have, I just want to know how to prefix `date ;` to every command

Comment: Are you looking for that `export PROMPT="%D %*>"`?

Comment: You could add the curren't time stamp to your `$PS1` like @nobody says - this has the disadvantage that it is not accurate, the prompt might have been sitting there for a while before you run your command.

Comment: You can use [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) and activate the `command_execution_time` segment. powerlevel10k also comes with a lot of other features.

Comment: Or the right prompt: `RPROMPT='%D{%T.%1.}'` (don't export those, put them in `~/.zshrc` instead).

Comment: There's also `TIMEFMT='%J took %*E' REPORTTIME=0` (`%*E` for elapsed time, there are many other resources you can print, see `into zsh TIMEFMT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `zsh` to print the current time every time `zle` accepts a line and `zsh` starts interpreting the code in it, you could do it in the `preexec()` hook:

```
print-time() print -P '%F{yellow}%D{%FT%T.%2.%z}%f'
preexec_functions+=(print-time)
```

To do it before each command, you could do it in a DEBUG trap:

```
TRAPDEBUG() print-time > /dev/tty
```

But I doubt you'd like that as it would really be run before every command, including those run in completion widgets and other hooks.

Note that you can also add the time to your right-prompt:

```
RPS1='%D{%T.%1.}'
```

Comment: Also note that `zsh` is not involved at all in the colouring of `ls`'s output. It's `ls` that colours its output itself (by  issuing the same kind of escape sequences that zsh does to change the foreground colour).